# Custom login and registration forms

Tags: customization, login, forms, user-registration

I want to create a custom register / login form for a specific user role in the WordPress system. The visitor should be able to register (to assign the right role immediately) and login to gain access to a specific page (which is only available for this specific role).

I've found some articles, where they check for $_POST parameters on top of the template file, and do all the logic there. I would prefer form handling in functions.php

Note: I'd also prefer to get solution with templates where I code the forms, and handle them in functions.php file. I have found an article stating that handling forms the right way is to send them to admin-post.php, and this works, but I cant get any validation in place. With new wp_error I cant display them when redirecting back..

Any input is highly appriciated!

EDIT:
In other words, I would love an in-depth answer or link to any article on how to handle custom forms and custom form validation. Prefered flow: custom template with markup and handling the form (maybe sending mail after submittion, creating users for registration forms, or maybe even adding posts in frontend) in functions.php

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I use this function as a plugin but you can use it also in function.php.

But i still didn't found a way to add the user role I used it like a textbox but also we can use it in select but I don't know if it works correctly I hope someone can add it if it's not correct.

```
<?php

/*
  Plugin Name: Registration Form
  Description: Custom sign up form.
  Version: 1.1
  Author: Me
 */



/////////////////
// PLUGIN CORE //
/////////////////

function cr(&$fields, &$errors) {

  // Check args and replace if necessary
  if (!is_array($fields))     $fields = array();
  if (!is_wp_error($errors))  $errors = new WP_Error;

  // Check for form submit
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Get fields from submitted form
    $fields = cr_get_fields();

    // Validate fields and produce errors
    if (cr_validate($fields, $errors)) {

      // If successful, register user
      wp_insert_user($fields);

      // And display a message
      echo 'Registration complete. Goto <a href="' . get_site_url() . '/wp-login.php">login page</a>.';

      // Clear field data
      $fields = array(); 
    }
  }

  // Santitize fields
  cr_sanitize($fields);

  // Generate form
  cr_display_form($fields, $errors);
}

function cr_sanitize(&$fields) {
  $fields['user_login']   =  isset($fields['user_login'])  ? sanitize_user($fields['user_login']) : '';
  $fields['user_pass']    =  isset($fields['user_pass'])   ? esc_attr($fields['user_pass']) : '';
  $fields['user_email']   =  isset($fields['user_email'])  ? sanitize_email($fields['user_email']) : '';
  $fields['user_url']     =  isset($fields['user_url'])    ? esc_url($fields['user_url']) : '';
  $fields['first_name']   =  isset($fields['first_name'])  ? sanitize_text_field($fields['first_name']) : '';
  $fields['last_name']    =  isset($fields['last_name'])   ? sanitize_text_field($fields['last_name']) : '';
  $fields['nickname']     =  isset($fields['nickname'])    ? sanitize_text_field($fields['nickname']) : '';
  $fields['description']  =  isset($fields['description']) ? esc_textarea($fields['description']) : '';
  $fields['role']  =  isset($fields['role']) ? esc_textarea($fields['role']) : '';
}

function cr_display_form($fields = array(), $errors = null) {

  // Check for wp error obj and see if it has any errors  
  if (is_wp_error($errors) && count($errors->get_error_messages()) > 0) {

    // Display errors
    ?><ul><?php
    foreach ($errors->get_error_messages() as $key => $val) {
      ?><li>
        <?php echo $val; ?>
      </li><?php
    }
    ?></ul><?php
  }

  // Disaply form

  ?><form action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
    <div>
      <label for="user_login">Username <strong>*</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="user_login" value="<?php echo (isset($fields['user_login']) ? $fields['user_login'] : '') ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="user_pass">Password <strong>*</strong></label>
      <input type="password" name="user_pass">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="email">Email <strong>*</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo (isset($fields['user_email']) ? $fields['user_email'] : '') ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="website">Website</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_url" value="<?php echo (isset($fields['user_url']) ? $fields['user_url'] : '') ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo (isset($fields['first_name']) ? $fields['first_name'] : '') ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="website">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo (isset($fields['last_name']) ? $fields['last_name'] : '') ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="role">Role : Author, Contributor, Editor and Subscriber</label>
      <input type="text" name="role" value="<?php echo (isset($fields['role']) ? $fields['role'] : '') ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="nickname">Nickname</label>
      <input type="text" name="nickname" value="<?php echo (isset($fields['nickname']) ? $fields['nickname'] : '') ?>">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="bio">About / Bio</label>
      <textarea name="description"><?php echo (isset($fields['description']) ? $fields['description'] : '') ?></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form><?php
}

function cr_get_fields() {
  return array(
    'user_login'   =>  isset($_POST['user_login'])   ?  $_POST['user_login']   :  '',
    'user_pass'    =>  isset($_POST['user_pass'])    ?  $_POST['user_pass']    :  '',
    'user_email'   =>  isset($_POST['user_email'])   ?  $_POST['user_email']        :  '',
    'user_url'     =>  isset($_POST['user_url'])     ?  $_POST['user_url']     :  '',
    'first_name'   =>  isset($_POST['first_name'])   ?  $_POST['first_name']        :  '',
    'last_name'    =>  isset($_POST['last_name'])    ?  $_POST['last_name']        :  '',
    'nickname'     =>  isset($_POST['nickname'])     ?  $_POST['nickname']     :  '',
    'description'  =>  isset($_POST['description'])  ?  $_POST['description']  :  '',
    'role'  =>  isset($_POST['role'])  ?  $_POST['role']  :  ''
  );
}

function cr_validate(&$fields, &$errors) {

  // Make sure there is a proper wp error obj
  // If not, make one
  if (!is_wp_error($errors))  $errors = new WP_Error;

  // Validate form data

  if (empty($fields['user_login']) || empty($fields['user_pass']) || empty($fields['user_email'])) {
    $errors->add('field', 'Required form field is missing');
  }

  if (strlen($fields['user_login']) < 4) {
    $errors->add('username_length', 'Username too short. At least 4 characters is required');
  }

  if (username_exists($fields['user_login']))
    $errors->add('user_name', 'Sorry, that username already exists!');

  if (!validate_username($fields['user_login'])) {
    $errors->add('username_invalid', 'Sorry, the username you entered is not valid');
  }

  if (strlen($fields['user_pass']) < 5) {
    $errors->add('user_pass', 'Password length must be greater than 5');
  }

  if (!is_email($fields['user_email'])) {
    $errors->add('email_invalid', 'Email is not valid');
  }

  if (email_exists($fields['user_email'])) {
    $errors->add('email', 'Email Already in use');
  }

  if (!empty($fields['user_url'])) {
    if (!filter_var($fields['user_url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
      $errors->add('user_url', 'Website is not a valid URL');
    }
  }

  // If errors were produced, fail
  if (count($errors->get_error_messages()) > 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Else, success!
  return true;


}



///////////////
// SHORTCODE //
///////////////

// The callback function for the [cr] shortcode
function cr_cb() {
  $fields = array();
  $errors = new WP_Error();

  // Buffer output
  ob_start();

  // Custom registration, go!
  cr($fields, $errors);

  // Return buffer
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('cr', 'cr_cb');
```

Comment: Yea I think I came across a simular tutorial, but I hate using shortcodes, and I want to be able to login the user after creating the user + redirecting them after it all.. With this method headers are allready sent, so you need to provide them with a login url.. Don't like that approach.. Thanks anyways for the input!